# Why is this code giving an "Unreachable Statement" error?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, unreachable-code

This is my code and im getting an unreachable statement error on it but i do not know why.

```
public boolean Boardload(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Color color3 = new Color(114, 46, 33);
    Color color4 = new Color(180, 0, 0);

    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 770);

        {
            while(false)
            {
                BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
                search: for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++)
                    {
                        if(image.getRGB(x, y) == color3.getRGB())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

the exact error is:

```
java:68: unreachable statement
         {
         ^
```

Help would be nice, this code is supposed to loop until the pixel is found.

Comment: Surely the code won't enter the loop 'while(false)' (it will never evaluate to true, so won't enter it). Is the return statement within there the problem?

Comment: You know while (false) does nothing right?

Comment: oh dont i feel dumb false what am i thinking

Comment: See my question just as a side note [Infinite loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570243/infinite-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that your loop is

```
while(false) {
```

This loop never executes, because `false != true`.  Consequently, the Java compiler is telling you that nothing in the body of the loop will ever execute, and hence it's unreachable.

Try changing your loop to

```
while (true) {
```

(the idiomatic "loop forever") and see if that fixes things.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

`while(false)` is always `false` and the loop body is never executed: **unreachable**. Change to `while (true)`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `while(false)` will never execute anything within that loop, thus it's all un-reachable.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but that is some smelly code.  I'm not sure what the braces/blocks are doing after declaring your Color local vars, and after declaring your Rectangle var.  The main problem for unreachability is `while(false)`, which means it will never execute the associated block.