# why I am not getting error in this java for loop?

Tags: java

> In below statement we will get unreachable statemnt error. I know what
>   is the reason behind that error.

```
for(;false;)
System.out.println("Unrechable statement");
```

> My question is why we'll not get error in below statemnt.

```
boolean b = false;
for(;b;)
System.out.println("NO error");
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000930/unreachable-statement-error-using-while-loop-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is compiler will consider that there may be a chance that `b` is being changes from its previous value to some other value by some other part of your program or thread, Even though your program is not actually  changing `b` but compiler will not detect it at compile time.
Clarification could be just make `b` as final & see you will get the same error because compiler will notice that `b` is final & can not be changed by other part of program so will consider `false` as final value of `b` & thus will produce error .

```java
final boolean b = false;
for(;b;)
System.out.println("NO error"); //error: unreachable statement
```