# Why is this unreachable code?

Tags: java, unreachable-code

Got a practice question, and I have the below code:

```
while (false) { x=3; }
```

The x=3 is unreachable code, and I don't really understand why. There is a similar section of code:

```
if (false) { x=3; }
```

which is perfectly valid.

May be a bit of a noob question, or may be I'm just missing something, but if you could help me understand why that'd be great, thanks!

I am asking specifically about the difference between the if and while statement, because the same line of code changed to if, is valid and will compile.

Comment: Code is unreachable means the compiler deemed it that there cannot be no path to statement `x=3;` because `while ( false )`can never be `true`

Comment: The kicker is: neither can `if(false)`. The real question is: why does the compiler not have problems with the if statement.

Comment: And for the second part of the question, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8570302/1743880

Comment: And refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299914/iffalse-vs-whilefalse-unreachable-code-vs-dead-code also

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, the other question is asking about if and not while statements!

Comment: Please refer to the above questions also. They explain this behaviour both for if and while statements, by referencing the Java specification. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299914/iffalse-vs-whilefalse-unreachable-code-vs-dead-code

Comment: It is a duplicate of this too which specifically mentions while loops. Whether it's an if or a loop, the answer is still the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302133/why-is-this-code-giving-an-unreachable-statement-error

Comment: Ok, well I had a look for questions previously asked and didn't find those, thanks for linking them

Comment: So essentially because it never starts as false to then become true, but it is actually true and then becomes false, the while loop will never execute, hence the unreachable code?

Answer (score 1):

Read below article it will answer your question:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21

> while statement can complete normally iff at least one of the
>   following is true:
>
> o    The while statement is reachable and the condition expression is
>   not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.
>
> o    There is a reachable break statement that exits the while
>   statement.
>
> The contained statement is reachable iff the while statement is
>   reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression
>   whose value is false.